# Subscription renewal not showing in latest_receipt_info

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

Our backend does server side receipt verification. In order to check the last expiration date for a renewable subscription, we look at the information in **latest_receipt_info**. This approach works most of the times.

However, we have some cases of users that, even with active subscriptions, **latest_receipt_info** only contains the initial subscription, which has already expired. I wonder if someone has already experienced this issue of having missing transactions. It looks extremely weird to me, because Apple is not returning the *right information*. These users were charged properly, but the Apple response does not reflect that. Am I missing something? Documentation is far from being great... Thanks!

Comment: Also getting this, exactly the same as your description.  `In App Purchase`, subscription based, back end server checks receipt for NON renewing subscription. Every now and again users report they have paid yet there subscription and it shows expired. Interestingly if they purchase again straight away it goes through correctly. Have not got the bottom of this yet.

Comment: I contacted Apple through Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS) and they replied it looked like a bug on their end. I have not received any update on the bug report yet, but when the next subscription expiration date came, it was renewed perfectly, no problems at all. Weird.

Comment: Thats interesting, thanks for replying with your findings, ive upvoted you.  Have they said they have fixed the bug? If not I might file need to file bug report/contact them to with my experience

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It's just a random thing. It happens every now and then. It just eventually goes through. 

What we normally do is to grant the affected user a promotional limited subscription (no cost, mainly give them access from our backend), and keep checking the receipt. Eventually, it is renewed by Apple. It's a frustrating system to deal with, for sure.